# Select local video, shorten length, then upload video in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I need any idea to do this with javascript in ruby on rails application.

I want the user to upload a video, then the file has to be shortened from either start or finish. The purpose of that is to make the video smaller in size.

Then the video should be uploaded to server.

I have looked at https://github.com/danielcebrian/rangeslider-videojs but maybe someone knows a better solution

For uploading I have looked at FFmpeg, for cropping the video server side.

Answer (score 0):

First off I should point out that if the editing process needs user interaction in the browser then this is not a simple problem, it's pretty complex and there's a lot of ways you could do it.

Uploading is a pretty easy part nowadays, as the built in rails ActiveStorage module works pretty well.

Now, if you don't need to edit videos in the browser, just want to clip them down to a specific size, then that is not too bad. You can indeed just have rails call ffmpeg with `system`. The `-ss` option is the flag you need, it's for cropping video.

If you do need user editing of videos in browser then you'll need to investigate a good JavaScript plugin for this, because it's not something that is going to be quick to write by hand.

Comment: Yes I am trying to find a simple slider like nouislider, so the user can select beginning or end of video to cut. then those variables should be send with to the ffmpeg to cut it in server side. Do you think it will be the best solution?